# oldbreader get the text cells as empty

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to read an excel file using oledbreader and oledbconnection the connection string is as follows
`@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FilePath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"`
when I try reading from the excel file some of the files work fine and give me the data I need but in other cases all columns that have a text value are shown as empty but it takes all the int or double values normally and without problems I looked around and found that some people changed the connection string to this

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + PrmPathExcelFile + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text"""
```

and after that it worked just fine. I tried that way but when I try to open connection I get isam error.
The file I read from is xlsx not xls if that helps ..

Comment: Does it work if you change the Excel 8.0; to Excel 12.0 Xml;?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this as connection string,

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+FilePath+";Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"
```

you are trying to import mixed types but while type guessing rows the column is datatype is treated as double, so text values are not coming.Using IMEX=1 solves this problem.